# ¿Cómo mostrar líneas que no inicien con un formato de hora y que no terminen con un formato de fecha? | UNIX

Tags: linux, unix, terminal

Sé que se utiliza el comando "grep" pero no sé exactamente como representarlo.

Mi idea sería `grep -v "^/.*/$"`

Quiero recalcar que con formato de horas y fechas no sé a cual exactamente se refiere, pero supongo que sería como por ejemplo xx/xx/xxxx (mes/dia/año).'

Intenté con `grep -v "^xx/xx/xxx/$"` pero no funcionó

Comment: no borres preguntas y vuelvas a publicarlas. En lugar de eso, edítalas y proporciona un [mcve]. De lo contrario, te acabarán bloqueando y no podrás preguntas. Como dije en la anterior pregunta: proporciona ejemplos de ficheros así como el resultado que se querría

Comment: Si defines el formato de hora y formato de fecha, algo para salir del paso seguramente podríamos redactar